# How do I tell RhinoMocks to return the same object passed as parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I'm using RhinoMock for my unit testing and I want to know how do set it up so a particular method always returns the same object it received as parameter.

This is the interface I want to mock:

```
public interface IItemRepository
{
    Item Craete(Item item);
}
```

I want to set up RhinoMocks in such a way that every time the Create method is called, the mocked stub will return the same object passed as the parameter.

This is my test initialization method:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void CrateServiceWithMockRepository()
{
    var stubRepository = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IItemRepository>();

    // ... how to set-up the stubRepository as described above ...

    // Create the target service for this unit test
    this.targetService = new ServiceXYZ(stubRepository);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Do` and pass a delegate to execute when the method is called:

```
stubRepository.Stub(r => r.Create(null)).IgnoreArguments()
    .Do(new Func<Item, Item>(item => item));
```